# Convert list of floats to comma separated string | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Given a **list** of **floats**:

```
my_list = [0.3, 0.11, -0.9]
```

I want a **string** literal object:

```
my_string = "0.3, 0.11, -0.9"
```

---

Attempt:

```
print(', '.join(inputs))
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

Answer (score 4):

**The compact way:**

```
l = [0.3, 0.11, -0.9]

print (str(l)[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
0.3, 0.11, -0.9
```

Still, to be used with caution :). The "regular" way would be:

```
print (', '.join([str(x) for x in l]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(' , '.join(str(x) for x in [0.3, 0.11, -0.9]))
```

Comment: Updated your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the easiest way would be to do:

```
my_string = str(my_list)[1:-1]
```

This takes `my_list`, converts it into a string, and takes the characters from 1)leaving the first character at 0) to -1 (the end character is not taken)

Comment: Oh, interesting. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

A more *pythonic* way is to use `map` to first convert all the `float` values to `str`, and then use the function `join` to concatenate into a string.

```
print(', '.join(map(str, my_list)))
```

This prints `0.3, 0.11, -0.9` when `my_list = [0.3, 0.11, -0.9]`

Answer (score -1):

you can use join function of string like this:

first you have to convert float to str

```
my_string = ', '.join([str(i) for i in my_list])
```

Comment: There are many syntax issues with this answer. I tried my_string = `', '.join([float(i) for i in inputs])` but got `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`.

Comment: you have to use str not float @ThePewCDestroyer